# Cutting Row with Data and moving to different sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to cut a row that has the specified cell blank and then paste it into another sheet  in the same workbook. My coding works fine to delete the row but everything I've tried to cut and paste keeps giving me errors. Here's the working code that deletes the rows:

```
Sub Remove()

    'Remove No Denovo &/or No Peak Seq
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    nLastRow = r.rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = r.Row

    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If Cells(n, "G") = "" Then Cells(n, "G").EntireRow.Delete
    Next n

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've changed the .Delete to .Cut, which works fine but when I add another line below that along the lines of Sheets("DENOVO").Range("A" & i).Paste (oh, and a line above with i = 1 and one below with i = i + 1) it gives me an error. I've tried .PasteSpecial and others, just too many to actually remember.

Comment: .Paste method is for Sheet Object only. So instead of deleting, you want to cut and paste it to another sheet? Same code above? Is that what you want?

Comment: I do want to cut from one sheet and paste to another. If a different code is necessary that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to cut and paste, see below:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("A1").Cut Sheeet2.Range("A1")
End With
```

Above cut's value in Cell A1 in Sheet1 and paste it on Cell A1 of Sheet2.
Now if you want to incorporate it in your code, see below.

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
With Activesheet
    For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If .Cells(n, "G") = "" Then
            .Cells(n, "G").EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")
            .Cells(n, "G").EntireRow.Delete '~~> if you want to delete
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Above code cuts all rows with Cell in G blank and paste it in Sheet2 starting A1.
**Note:** Sheet2 and Sheet1 that I used above are sheet codenames.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it also remove the row so there isn't a blank row? I know how to do it otherwise but can it be incorporated?

Comment: Yes, it can be incorporated. Add your previous code to delete after cutting it. See my edit.

Comment: Oh, I kind of feel a little dumb now. Thanks!