# Move specific row to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How could I move a complete row (or rows) of sheet1, if on that row the column C  have the word "solved", to the first empty row of sheet2?

The other rows which do not match the condition would need to continue in sheet 1 but occupying the empty rows, if is the case (to not have spaces between all rows).

Comment: What are you trying to ask ?

Comment: if i find one keyword in a specific column, to move the entire row to a other sheet ( first empty row found) :)

Comment: This has been asked and answered many many times, did you try google?  If you have code that is not working edit you post with the code.

Comment: actually i couldnt find.. because i want to look to a specific column to match a "keyword"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131874/cutting-row-with-data-and-moving-to-different-sheet-vba) will do it you just need to change the criteria and columns to meet your needs.  Took two minutes on google.

Comment: @ScottCraner Understood. I'll delete my comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly as you want:

```
Sub Gonzalo()

    Const SEARCH_COLUMN = 3
    Const KEYWORD = "solved"

    Dim n&
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Err = 0
        n = Application.Match(KEYWORD, Sheet1.Columns(SEARCH_COLUMN), 0)
        If Err = 0 Then
            Sheet2.Rows(Sheet2.[index(a:a,1+max(iferror(match({"*";9E+99},a:a,{-1;1}),1)))].Row) = Sheet1.Rows(n).Value
            Sheet1.Rows(n).Delete xlUp
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Note: use the first two lines to edit the search column and the keyword to search for.

Comment: thanks for your input. It works partially.. its just moving 1 row (the first found) and deletes all others with solved (without moving them). Any chance it could place the rows starting in B3 of sheet 2?

Comment: I tested it before posting. It moves all the rows here that contain "solved" in column C. Yes it can be modified to start in B3 of destination. But there must be something unexplained in your source data. Any chance you can send me a sample? I'll sort it out quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com