# VBA cut and paste row to another sheet based on cell value and delete empty row

Tags: vba, excel, paste, delete-row

Hi I have almost no experience coding. I took a crappy high school course, but I need to create code to cut rows from one sheet to the next empty line on another "archive" sheet when a condition (ex cell F) has data in it. Then delete the now empty row that was cut from. Ideally this would be done once the worksheet was saved as well. I've found a few things that come close but for some reason they won't work
I'm using Excel 2016 if that helps

[This solution was close but didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131874/cutting-row-with-data-and-moving-to-different-sheet-vba)

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: please share the code you have written and tell us which part of it is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the solution you link in your question, changing

```
If .Cells(n, "G") = "" Then
```

to

```
If .Cells(n, "G") <> "" Then
```

should accomplish your objective of copy-paste-deleting rows with data in the given column "G"